# How can I remove impurities from water easily when my water purifier is not working?

Tags: cleaning, substitute-tool, kitchen, water

There are some situation where I have to face this problem when my water purifier is not working properly. So what I can do so that I can remove impurities from water. There are some issues with water at my home so is there anything which I can do to manage at least for 2 or 3 days.

Comment: What kind of impurities do you want to filter out? Different levels of pollution require different techniques.

Comment: Yes, what @Hobbes said. And what are the specific issues with water at your home?

Comment: It's not clear if the techniques of water purification is a "hack" that needs thinking outside the box. But as a matter of sharing knowledge, when folks are only guessing what types of chemicals or pathogens you are trying to remove, it becomes somewhat concerning that this information might get someone really sick or worse if someone else relies on the advice given here without the proper context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on the specific situation, often times boiling water is enough to kill the bacteria and pathogens that may be found in contaminated water.

If you are looking to filter out minerals or microscopic debris/particulates, perhaps running the water through a coffee machine with charcoal crumbles used as "grounds" will help the situation. not only will the water be heated up to a hot temperature to kill organisms, but it will also be filtered through the charcoal.

Answer (score 2):

You can also find iodine tablets in most sporting goods stores. You can also add a little bit of bleach to your water. The tablets are easy to use, and I'm not sure how much bleach to use because adding too much is dangerous.

Truthfully though, as was previously mentioned boiling is your best option. If you have a distiller you could distill the water. Or to make one boil water and place something over the pot to collect the steam like a small tarp, then let the steam cool and form back into water and collect the water. With the tarp make sure the low end of the tarp is not over you pan so that water will drop down for you to catch.

Edit: drinking distiller water is not good for your health if taken in either large quantities or over a long period of time. Osmosis will leach the electrolytes from you into the water and could eventually kill you. But for a short period of time in normal quantities you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a folded muslin cloth (folding will create multiple layers) to filter out suspended impurities. After that you can use potassium permanganate to disinfect it (if you cannot boil the water). Potassium permanganate is available in all drug stores.
Coming to the concentration of potassium permanganate, this - [EPA guidelines](http://www.epa.gov/ogwdw/mdbp/pdf/alter/chapt_5.pdf), will help you out. If you don't get any muslin cloth, you can also use filter paper(costly when compared to muslin cloth and not reusable) used to prepare coffee, etc.